# Java ServiceLoader wrapper not working, internally using calling class

Tags: java, module, serviceloader

So, I've been trying to make a small `PluginLoader` in my library which allows you to load `JAR` files into a custom `ModuleLayer` and use the layer to load services using `ServiceLoader.load(ModuleLayer, Class<?>)`.

However, when calling `ServiceProvider.load`, it internally uses `Reflection.getCallerClass` to get the, duhh, class calling the code, so it can load the services from it's module.

PluginLoader.java

```java
package com.wexalian.common.plugin;

import com.wexalian.common.collection.wrapper.StreamWrapper;
import com.wexalian.nullability.annotations.Nonnull;

import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.util.ServiceLoader;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

@FunctionalInterface
public interface PluginLoader<T extends IAbstractPlugin> extends StreamWrapper.Iterable<T> {
    @Nonnull
    @Override
    Stream<T> get();
    
    static void init(@Nonnull ServiceLoaderLayerFunction serviceLoaderFunc) {
        PluginLoaderImpl.init(serviceLoaderFunc);
    }
    
    static void loadPlugins(@Nonnull Path path) {
        PluginLoaderImpl.loadPlugins(path);
    }
    
    @Nonnull
    static <T extends IAbstractPlugin> PluginLoader<T> load(@Nonnull Class<T> pluginClass) {
        return load(pluginClass, null);
    }
    
    @Nonnull
    static <T extends IAbstractPlugin> PluginLoader<T> load(@Nonnull Class<T> pluginClass, ServiceLoaderFallbackFunction fallbackServiceProvider) {
        return PluginLoaderImpl.load(pluginClass, fallbackServiceProvider);
    }
    
    @FunctionalInterface
    interface ServiceLoaderLayerFunction {
        @Nonnull
        <T> ServiceLoader<T> load(@Nonnull ModuleLayer layer, @Nonnull Class<T> clazz);
        
        @Nonnull
        default <T> Stream<T> stream(@Nonnull ModuleLayer layer, @Nonnull Class<T> clazz) {
            return load(layer, clazz).stream().map(ServiceLoader.Provider::get);
        }
    }
    
    @FunctionalInterface
    interface ServiceLoaderFallbackFunction {
        @Nonnull
        <T> ServiceLoader<T> load(@Nonnull Class<T> clazz);
        
        @Nonnull
        default <T> Stream<T> stream(@Nonnull Class<T> clazz) {
            return load(clazz).stream().map(ServiceLoader.Provider::get);
        }
    }
}
```

PluginLoaderImpl.java

```java
package com.wexalian.common.plugin;

import com.wexalian.nullability.annotations.Nonnull;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.module.Configuration;
import java.lang.module.ModuleFinder;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

final class PluginLoaderImpl {
    private static final Set<ModuleLayer> pluginLayerSet = new HashSet<>();
    
    private static PluginLoader.ServiceLoaderLayerFunction serviceLoaderLayer;
    private static ModuleLayer coreLayer;
    private static ClassLoader coreLoader;
    
    private static boolean init = false;
    
    private PluginLoaderImpl() {}
    
    static void init(@Nonnull PluginLoader.ServiceLoaderLayerFunction serviceLoaderFunc) {
        if (!init) {
            serviceLoaderLayer = serviceLoaderFunc;
            
            Class<?> coreClass = StackWalker.getInstance(StackWalker.Option.RETAIN_CLASS_REFERENCE).getCallerClass();
            coreLayer = coreClass.getModule().getLayer();
            coreLoader = coreClass.getClassLoader();
            
            if (coreLayer == null) {
                throw new IllegalStateException("PluginLoaderImpl can only be initialized from a named module!");
            }
            else init = true;
        }
        else throw new IllegalStateException("PluginLoaderImpl can only be initialized once!");
    }
    
    static void loadPlugins(@Nonnull Path path) {
        if (init) {
            if (Files.exists(path)) {
                try (Stream<Path> paths = Files.list(path)) {
                    ModuleFinder moduleFinder = ModuleFinder.of(paths.toArray(Path[]::new));
                    List<String> moduleNames = moduleFinder.findAll().stream().map(ref -> ref.descriptor().name()).toList();
                    Configuration configuration = coreLayer.configuration().resolveAndBind(moduleFinder, ModuleFinder.of(), moduleNames);
                    ModuleLayer pluginLayer = coreLayer.defineModulesWithOneLoader(configuration, coreLoader);
                    pluginLayerSet.add(pluginLayer);
                }
                catch (IOException e) {
                    throw new IllegalStateException("Error loading plugins from path " + path, e);
                }
            }
        }
        else throw new IllegalStateException("PluginLoaderImpl has to be initialized before you can load plugins!");
    }
    
    static <T extends IAbstractPlugin> PluginLoader<T> load(Class<T> clazz, PluginLoader.ServiceLoaderFallbackFunction serviceLoader) {
        if (init) {
            if (!pluginLayerSet.isEmpty()) {
                return () -> pluginLayerSet.stream().flatMap(layer -> serviceLoaderLayer.stream(layer, clazz)).filter(IAbstractPlugin::isEnabled);
            }
            else {
                return () -> serviceLoaderLayer.stream(coreLayer, clazz).filter(IAbstractPlugin::isEnabled);
            }
        }
        else if (serviceLoader != null) {
            return () -> serviceLoader.stream(clazz);
        }
        else throw new IllegalStateException("PluginLoaderImpl has to be initialized before you can load services from plugins!");
    }
}
```

Now my problem is:
I am currently writing a program with some services, and using that library to load JAR files and load them. However, it recognizes the `PluginLoader` as the caller class, which "does not declare uses", because the library doesn't actually have the service I want.

I have found a work around, which is accepting a `Function<ModuleLayer, Class<?>, ServiceProvider<?>`, which redirects all the calls to the proper module, but I'd rather not do that everywhere I use my `PluginLoader`.

Other than this I wouldn't know any other solution, so maybe one of you knows.

Thanks in advance,
Wexalian

Answer (score 0):

When using the ModuleLayer system, you also have to define the `uses` and `provides` in your and the various plugin module definitions.

Your module:

```
uses com.wexalian.common.plugin.IAbstractPlugin;
```

And in your plugin modules:

```
provides com.wexalian.common.plugin.IAbstractPlugin with some.plugin.PluginFactory;
```

See [ServiceLoader](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ServiceLoader.html) and [ServiceLoader.Provider](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ServiceLoader.Provider.html), this is how the service loader in one module knows about loaders in other modules.

Comment: That's not my problem. I'm writing a program which uses a library which calls ServiceLoader. ServiceLoader is activaly checking the caller class, e.g. one in the library, to see if it uses the interface. Which it can't because it's from a different module, my program.

Comment: @Wexalian then it would be the duty of that library to call [`addUses`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Module.html#addUses(java.lang.Class)) before calling into `ServiceLoader`.